# How to convert a insert statement into ssis package

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a insert statement

```
insert into table_source(colomn_1, colomn_2, colomn_3) select a,b,c from (select a,b,c from table_dest dest1 join table_dest_2 dest2 on dest1.a = dest2.a1 where dest2.b1 in ('101,'201','303') new_dest
```

i am trying to convert this sql query into a ssis package. should i use the 'execute sql task' or

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use Execute SQL Task.